# How to present the same current view controller from itself

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app where a storyboard's text is altered every time the next button is pressed but I would like a segue type animation every time the next button is pressed

I have tried calling a segue leading to the view controller but it called SIGABART

```swift
    public func segue() {

        var slide: [String] = GetText().Main(text: .info(0, 0))

        print(slide)

        SectionViewController().setValues(title: slide[1], buttonTitle: slide[3], body: slide[2])

        performSegue(withIdentifier: slide[0], sender: nil)
    }
```

I have also tried

```swift
let vc = SectionViewController() //my view controller class
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But it sais `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` When trying to update a label

I expected the view controller to pop up again with the animation but it crashes with SIGABART possibly because the view controller doesn't 'own' the segue

Comment: Present it programatically instead of using the segue.

Comment: @PGDev I tried that but it won't let me edit the elements. Eg `Label.text = "hi"` won't work

Comment: You call "setValues" on another instance than being presented from performSegue. 
In your other solution you apparently try to access the label before viewDidLoad has been called.

Comment: The labels are being set in viewDidLoad and setValues only edits variables in the current class

Comment: In a storyboard environment the default initializer `SectionViewController()` does **never** return the instance in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Segue`, present another instance of `SectionViewController` programatically from `SectionViewController` like,

```
class SectionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func setValues(title: String, buttonTitle: String) {
        label.text = title
        //add your code...
    }

    func showSectionVC() {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SectionViewController") as? SectionViewController {
            vc.setValues(title: "", buttonTitle: "")
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Call `showSectionVC()` from wherever you want to present `SectionViewController` in the already presented `SectionViewController`.

Also, don't forget to connect the `outlet` of `label` in `SectionViewController` properly.

Comment: It should be noted that you have to set the "Storyboard ID" in the storyboard (click on the VC in the storyboard and then in the 3th tab) to "SectionViewController". Otherwise its going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
let vc = SectionViewController()
vc.textForLabel = "test"
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and after in your SectionViewController viewDidLoad method, just

```
self.yourLabel.text = self.textForLabel
```

I think you getting crash because you try to update text on label, but label is not loaded and prepared
So, the decision is save you data, like text in this sample, and update your UI in view did load - your label will be loaded here.

Comment: This method works on my other view controller presenting to a different view controller but I am in the SectionViewController and trying to present to itself which results in errors

Comment: so, what about vc.textForLabel = yourLabel.text? you can "cache" you previous value